# How to auto-size all columns in a sheet with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating excel files in `Java` with `Apache POI 3`. The default width of the columns are not enough to show the full contents of some cells. I found the method `autosizeColumn(int column)` in the `Sheet` interface which works for individual columns, but I am wondering how to do it for all columns in a sheet and maybe only to some columns if they contain a certain value in their first cell.

for example:

```
if(cell.getStringCellValue().equals("some value")){
    //autosize or set the width to a certain value for this cell's column
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What about iterating over the columns and call `autosizeColumn()` for each of them?

Comment: yes that could work @RobertKock haven't thought of that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could set the `DefaultColumnWidth` as below, if you wanted to resize all columns. Default width is 8, for reference, so the below example sets it to be 50% wider.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(12);
```